# How to replace / with comma using php?

Tags: php, string

I have a variable `$mobileno` which contains mobile number and sometimes multiple number separated by /(Forward slash) and I used the following code to replace the slash(/) with comma(,). But my code isn't working.

```
$str = str_replace('9875647362/985634758', ',', $str);
 //mobile numbers are stored in $mobileno
print_r($str);//expected output is 9875647362,985634758
```

Please help me.

Comment: `$str = '9875647362/985634758'; $str = str_replace('/', ',', $str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `str_replace()` is

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

So try with this

```
$str = str_replace('/', ',', '9875647362/985634758');
```

Comment: This answer _actually_ tells why the OP was wrong. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "9875647362/985634758";
$str = str_replace('/', ',', $str);
print_r($str);
```

Output : `9875647362,985634758`

Answer (score 2):

str_replace doesnt work that way

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count);
```

in your example that would make it

```
$str = str_replace("/", ',', $str);
```